# Adding credentials to env using `cat` with python-dotenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, dotenv

I am trying to get my credentials into env when using python-dotenv. I previously used

```
export CREDS=`cat $PATH_TO_CREDS_JSON`
```

in my .zshrc file.

I have attempted to use the `cat` command as before but it is saved as a string.

Printing it led to the string value of `cat $PATH_TO_CREDS` being saved to the env variable.

I have tried it with different quotes and without quotes.

This is the code I have in my main called python file.

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv

path = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), "devlocal/.env")
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=path, override=True, verbose=True)
```

My .env file is

```
CREDS=`cat $PATH_TO_CREDS_JSON`
```

this.

I would expect `os.getenv('CREDS')` to result in a json formatted file containing my credentials. Sadly it just returns the string of the command.

Answer (score 0):

You should define each value of your credentials separately in your .env file.
For example if your json looks like this:

```
{"username": "example1", "password": "example2"}
```

Then your .env should look like this:

```
USERNAME=example1
PASSWORD=example2
```

You can then join them up like this:

```
import json
...
creds = json.dumps({"username": os.getenv('USERNAME'), "password": os.getenv('PASSWORD')})
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your answer, sadly GCP requires the entire file to be one big credential, I will have a look if it is feasible to maybe do that and then join them up.

Comment: Thank you Toni, I will try it out and will accept your answer if it works!

Comment: Hi Toni, I had a look and this is more complicated than our current solution of just adding the creds to env using `cat`.